# Dribble API Json code Wont Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, jsonp

I have this code

```
// Dribble
$('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.dribbble.com/players/simplebits/shots?callback=displayShots" charset="utf-8"><\/script>');
function displayShots(data) {
    shots = data.shots;
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var shot = shots[i];
        $('#dribble').append('..somecode..');
    }
}
//
```

when I paste it on console it will load

but when I place it on `$(document).ready` it doesn't work,

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are declaring inside the scope of document.ready closure, you either should use:

```
   window.displayShots = function(data) {
      shots = data.shots;
      for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var shot = shots[i];
        $('#dribble').append('..somecode..');
      }
    }
```

or put your callback function outside of document.ready callback

Comment: Best way would be using revealing module pattern of course, but I've tried to fix the problem with minimal changes so it wouldn't be hard to understand.

Comment: You should consider using new syntax $.ajax({...options...}).done(function(data){ ...code... })